# visual studio 2010 Step Into function doesn't work properly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Anyone else having issues with using F11 to step into code?

Until about an hour ago, I was able to perfectly step through code in both C# and C++ projects with ease, but now I suddenly have to press F11 at least 10 times before it will goto the next line. It's not even an issue of lag, as pressing and waiting has no result, it literally has to be hit 10 times every time I want to step into code. The same applies to the button on the GUI.

It started after playing with the Immediate and Command Window's (which are really useful by the way), I didn't use any commands that dealt with stepping into code, just commands for starting and stopping debugging.

Could I have accidentally enabled a "Make debugging retarded" option?

Googled everywhere for a solution, seems everyones had F11 problems but nothing like this, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you use the toolbar buttons instead of the F11 key, does it work better?

Comment: It has exactly the same behaviour as F11, I have to click it repeatedly

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Step Into' is suddenly not working in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801385/step-into-is-suddenly-not-working-in-visual-studio)